# How can I expand the scrollbar width smoothly using transition/animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, transition

I am trying to expand scrollbar width smoothly using transition. I can expand it adding a class to custom scrollbar. But how can I do the expansion smoothly?

CSS

```
.articles-container
{
    transition: width 2s ease-in-out; 
}
.articles-container::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    width: 20px;      
    transition: width 2s ease-in-out;  
}
.articles-container.expanded::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    width: 30px;
    transition: width 2s ease-in-out; 
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  var myDiv = document.querySelector('.articles-container');
  // bunch of onscrollbar calculations here

  if (onscrollbar) 
  {
    // console.log('Mouse is on the scrollbar');
    myDiv.classList.add('expanded');
  } 
  else 
  {
    // console.log('Mouse is not on the scrollbar');
    myDiv.classList.remove('expanded');
  }
```

How can I add a transition or animation to the width? The way I tried isn't working. Any other way of doing this? Please I need help

Comment: I don't think scrollbars can be animated

Comment: I have seen it on websites. I think the new windows 11 or on mac os or something like that has this effect built-in to the browser.